# Printing the address of a variable in Fortran 77

Tags: pointers, printing, fortran77

How can I print the address of a variable in Fortran 77?  Example:

```
      subroutine foo

      integer d3
c Now I want to print "Address of d3: " followed by its address.
```

The equivalent in C, of course, is

```
int d3;
printf("Address of d3: %p\n", &d3);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not technically Fortran 77, most fortran compilers provide a LOC function to get the address of an variable.

See:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/LOC.html

Comment: Thanks!  I actually knew about the loc function, but only saw it in the context of Cray pointers and didn't know how to use it to print an address.  The page to which you referred has a helpful example.